# Sass mixin keyframes and include vendor based properties

Tags: sass, include, compass, vendor-prefix

Trying to create a mixin for keyframes which will use an include for a vendor based property.

```
@mixin vendor($property, $value) {
    -webkit-#{$property}: #{$value};
    -moz-#{$property}: #{$value};
    #{$property}: #{$value};
}

@mixin keyframes($name) {
    @-webkit-keyframes #{$name} {
        @content;
    }
    @-moz-keyframes #{$name} {
        @content;
    }
    @keyframes #{$name} {
        @content;
    }
}

@include keyframes(scale) {
    0% {
        @include vendor(transform, scale(1) );
    }
    100% {
        @include vendor(transform, scale(2) );
    }
}
```

But how to prevent writing unnecessary vendors properties to the vendor based keyframes?

```
@-moz-keyframes scale {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
...
```

Comment: The best option is to use an autoprefixer plug in for your favorite compiler. No need to create any mixin. The autoprefixer will take care of all the vendor prefixes for all the necessary css properties. If you can point the complier i can add an answer to use the autoprefixer.